# Node.js内でPythonを呼び出して相互に変数をやり取りしたい

Tags: python, node.js

Node.js+Expressフレームワークを使ってWEBアプリケーションを作成しています。

Node.js内に3次方程式の解を求めるようなプログラムを組み込みたいのですが
自力で実装すると大変そうなので、Pythonのライブラリの力を借りようと思いました。

以下のように、PythonのSymPyモジュールを使って3つの解を求めて、解をsol変数を入れ
sol変数をNode.jsの変数に渡すような処理をしたいです。

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x') #文字'x'を変数xとして定義

#4x^3+12x^2+8x=0の解を求めて変数solに代入
sol=solve(4*x**3+12*x**2+8*x, x)
```

こういった処理は、Node.jsのpython-shellモジュールなどを使えばできるのでしょうか？
https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

python-shellの使い方を読んでもあまり理解が出来ませんでした。
以下のような使い方をするのではないかと色々触ってみたのですがエラーで全然前に進めません。

```
//まずpython-shellモジュールを読み込む
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

//json形式で別ファイルのpython(script.py)にデータを渡すことを前提にオブジェクト作成
var shell = new PythonShell('script.py', { mode: 'json '});

//jsonデータ作成
var json = {
    "a": "4",
    "b": "12",
    "c": "8"
}

//pythonにjsonデータを渡してpythonから返り値を受け取る
var test = shell.receive(json);
```

どうしたら出来ますか...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-shellモジュールのテスト](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/blob/master/test/test-python-shell.ts#L191)が参考になると思います。

まず、今回作成したJSONデータをnode.jsからPython側に送るには、sendメソッドを使う必要があります。

```
shell.send(json);
```

Python側のスクリプトは[このように](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/blob/master/test/python/echo_json.py)書くとよいようです。すなわち、標準入力にJSONを表す文字列が送られてくるので、それを`json.loads`でデコードします。
計算が終わってnode.js側に送り返すデータは`json.dumps`で文字列にしたあとprintで標準出力に出力します。

そして、Python側から送られてきたJSONデータは、ドキュメントによればmessageイベントで受け取ることができます。

```
shell.on('message', function (data) {
    // Pythonスクリプトから送られてきたデータを表示
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

以上をまとめると、次のようにすればできます。

**index.js**

```
//まずpython-shellモジュールを読み込む
var { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');

//json形式で別ファイルのpython(script.py)にデータを渡すことを前提にオブジェクト作成
var shell = new PythonShell('script.py', {
    mode: 'json',
});

//jsonデータ作成
var json = {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 12,
    "c": 8,
};

// scirpt.pyにJSONを送信
shell.send(json);

// script.pyからの返事を待機
shell.on('message', data => {
    // データを表示 
    console.log(data.result);
});

// 入力を終了
shell.end();
```

**script.py**

```
import sys, json
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x') #文字'x'を変数xとして定義

# nodejsスクリプトからデータを受信
data = json.loads(sys.stdin.readline())
a = data["a"]
b = data["b"]
c = data["c"]

# 方程式の解を求める
sol=solve(a*x**3+b*x**2+c*x, x)

# 各解をintに変換
intsol = [int(value) for value in sol]

# オブジェクトを作成
response = {"result": intsol}
# JSON文字列にして出力
print(json.dumps(response))
```

これを実行すると`[ -2, -1, 0 ]`のように表示され、正しく解が求まっていることが分かります。

---

とりあえずこのスクリプトを実行すれば動きますが、質問文にある元のスクリプトからはいくつか変わっているので注意してください。
例えば1行目のrequireの行が少し変わっています。元のままだと`PythonShell`をnewできないというエラーが出るはずです。
また、`{ mode: 'json ' }`という部分ですが、`'json '`という文字列に余計なスペースが含まれておりこれでは正しく動かないはずです。

Comment: 'script.py'の置き場所はどこにするのが適切でしょうか？

index.jsと同じフォルダ内にscript.pyを置いて実行すると
「python3: can't open file 'script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory」
というエラーが出ました。

'script.py'の記述を、'./script.py'などに変えてみてもだめでした。

Comment: 私はindex.jsと同じ場所にscript.pyを置いたら動作しました。 `script.py`の指定は実行時のカレントディレクトリからの相対パスとする必要があるらしいので、`index.js`をどのように実行しているかによって適切な方法が異なるかもしれません。 `__dirname`を用いて`index.js`からの相対パスとして記述するのもよいかと思います（参考： https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/issues/54 ）

Comment: パスの記述を(__dirname+'script.py')とすると、先程のErrorがでなくなりました。ただ、新たに「Traceback (most recent call last):」というエラーが出るようになりました。Pythonファイル内のSymPyに関する記述を削除するとこのErrorは出なくなるようです...。

Comment: 残念ながら、それだけだとエラーの情報が少なく何が悪いのか分かりません。`script.py`を直接実行して`{"a":4,"b":12,"c":8}`のような入力を与えてみることでより詳細なエラーの情報が分かると思います。

Comment: 「$ python script.py」で直接実行すると、「Traceback (most recent call last):File "script.py", line 2, in <module> from sympy import *
ImportError: No module named sympy」となります。このError文にしたがって、 「$ pip install sympy」を実行してsympyをインストールしようとすると、「Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)～～～」といったErrorが出るようです。

Comment: sympyをインストールできないという状態ですね。話がそれてきましたし、このコメント欄で話を続けるのは不便なので、新しい質問を作ってお聞きになることをおすすめします。特に、エラーメッセージは途中で省略されると分からないことが多いので、省略せずに全部を質問文に載せるようにするとよいと思います。